# Unable to install busybox-initramfs 15.04

Tags: server, 15.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 15.04 server on a machine.

During installation is stopped installing with the following error: An error was returned while trying to install the busybox-initramfs package onto the target system.

Ubuntu 15.04 desktop installs fine, but not server.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue on Ubuntu Server 14.04 i386 and did this to solve it.

**/boot partition separate**, outside of root partition, formated with ext3(with error it was ext4)
After that, the installation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue with 14.04. Problem repeated three separate times with nothing obvious I could find in `/var/log/syslog`. I  the end the solution was to make a new USB installer. Some things to keep in mind

- Check MD5 sum of installer to check the download is not corrupt. Checksums are available from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/), click on your version folder, then download the list of MD5SUMS. Locally run:

  `md5sum <path_to_iso_you_downloaded>`

  If it doesn't match you should download again
- Consider a new USB stick, hardware is unlikely the cause but USB sticks are generally plentiful.
- If it still fails you can drop open a shell and check the syslog for clues about what is going on.